# How does a const-qualifier on a member function affect overload resolution?

Tags: c++, class, overloading, overload-resolution, function-qualifier

Assume you have a class T with two member functions

1. `char foo() const {...}`
2. `char foo() {...}`.

It is my understanding that when called for a constant T, we resolve to (1); and for a non-constant T, we resolve to (2).

1. is that correct?
2. which rule is invoked in this resolution? (reference to standard great, but a helpful brief summary appreciated)

Notes:

1. I tried to google for it, but old hits I got on SO were cases for other overload resolutions involving const. However, link to an old SO actually explaining the above obviously great.
2. This came up when re-reading Stroustrup's "The C++ programming language", 2nd edition ("Special Edition"), String/Cref example in section 11.12, p. 296. As Stroustrup is so precise, the answer might be in previous sections, but I fail to see where. Reference to sections in Stroustrup very welcome too (2nd edition best as this is the one I have). Section 10.2.6 introduces const members as those "that don't change an object's value", which hints at the answer, but doesn't strike me as a clear resolution directive.

Comment: On a high level view, you can think on the transformation that the compiler will do. The member functions would be transformed into: `char foo(T const *this)` and `char foo(T *this)` (details aside).

Comment: @David Rodriguez - dribeas: I see; and for pointer type arguments, const p and p are distinguished in overload resolution, correct?This does give some intuition.

Comment: I’ve reformatted your question properly. Please take a moment to read the [Markdown formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: appreciated. Problem is when I use my iPhone as I'm away from my computer: I'm familiar with proper formatting, but phone is known to add/remove non-printables. It looks right on my phone, but isn't. I usually edit myself once at home, but didn't want to wait until midnight to ask question.

Comment: @gnometorule Fair point. :)

Comment: The additional `T*` / `T const*` parameter is called the *implicit object parameter* (it's actually a reference, though); I don't see why this should be a high level view. There are some details different between the implicit object parameter and actual function parameters, but AFAIK the greater part of overload resolution treats them equally. See [over.match.funcs]

Comment: @dyp: Not sure about what you mean with *it's actually a reference*. In the language it is really neither of them. If you go down to the implementation it is a *pointer* (the address of the object). These are the details I omitted and why the above is a *high level* view (actually middle level)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas According to [over.match.funcs], the implicit object parameter is a reference. I don't mean that in the sense that something must be passed in order to set the `this` pointer; I mean the overload resolution mechanism using a "fictional" additional parameter + argument.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63338608/get-address-of-const-method

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In N3242 (the standard draft I have on hand), 13.3.1 paragraph 4 says

> the type of the implicit object parameter is "lvalue reference to *cv* X” for [non-static member] functions declared without a
>   ref-qualifier or with the & ref-qualifier

this means that type of the implicit object argument, which occurs first, is an "lvalue reference to `cv X`", where `X` is the class, and `cv` is the cv-qualification of the member variable (i.e. const or non-const).  Then, overload resolution continues as normal.

To review the overload resolution process, first, both are listed as "candidate" functions as they are in the correct scope and have the correct name.

In the `const` case, only the `const` member function gets to the next step (called "viability"), so it's automatically the best choice.  The non-const member function is not viable because you can't convert a `const` reference into a non-const reference.

In the non-const case, both the const and non-const versions are viable, but the non-const one is "better" because of the fifth rule of 13.3.3.2 paragraph 3, quoted below.

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than
>   standard conversion sequence S2 if ...
>
> S1 and S2 are reference bindings, and the types to which the
>   references refer are the same type except for top-level cv-qualifiers,
>   and the type to which the reference initialized by S2 refers is more
>   cv-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by S1
>   refers.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, but (a) shouldn't the quote continue? It seems to be "if type is (...)", but appears to miss "then (...)"; (b) the quote applies to t*member* functions, correct? (quote says function only.

Comment: sorry, that got lost as it was mentioned in the sentence above.  Does it make sense now?

Comment: I see you already addressed (b) (thanks); what about (a)? (or tell me if/why (a) doesn't matter)

Comment: sorry, I don't understand.  I added in more context recently.  Basically it's saying, for non-static member function declared without a ref-qualifier (your case), the implicit object parameter is a reference to X with whatever cv state the function was declared with.  I don't see any conditionals that haven't been met.

Comment: after that point, the overload resolution treats the implicit object parameter exactly the same as any other argument, only that it occurs first.

Comment: thanks @dyp.  Found the equivalent rule in N3242 and included it.  Look good?

Comment: I see how my (a) makes little sense. However, doesn't the above quote only apply to *const* member functions? Maybe I'm mis-reading it, but I read the current version such that for *any* member function, the implicit object parameter will be consider a const ref; but I understand your explanation such that it would only apply to const member functions (as seems to make sense).

Comment: Yeah.. I missed one possible ranking of reference bindings in my comment: derived-to-base conversion. But it seems that's irrelevant for implicit object parameters: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43afc78eabcf247c

Comment: gnometorule: sorry, I think my answer was unclear.  The const-ness (i.e., cv-qualification in standards speak) of the implicit object argument is the same as the const-ness of the member function.  I've just edited and hopefully that part makes a bit more sense now.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying and (with @dyp and DR) actually teaching me something interesting. I thought cv meant constant value.

Comment: the v stands for volatile, as it's part of the same qualification.