# Why is this method called instead of the other?

Tags: c++, methods, reference, constants

I have this particular code sample:

```
 struct ComplexNumber {
      float  _Re, _Im;
     public:
      float  Re() const { return _Re; }
      float& Re()       { return _Re; }

      float  Im() const { return _Im; }
      float& Im()       { return _Im; }
    };
```

and I would like to know why, when I perform

```
ComplexNumber Num1;
cout << Num1.Re() << endl;
```

the method `float& Re() { return _Re; }` is being called, instead of

`float Re() const { return _Re; }` which seems to be well prepared to perform cout by securing the data with const.

Comment: I'm nearly certain [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469135/overload-resolution-c-for-const-member-functions) and its [selected answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21469596/1322972) describe what you're seeing.

Answer (score 3):

The best matching function is being called, so if you have both const and non const version, the non const version will be called on a non const object.

If you had a const object (or a pointer or reference)

```
const ComplexNumber Num1;
cout << Num1.Re() << endl;
```

then `float Re() const { return _Re; }` would be called.

Comment: I can remove `float& Re() { return _Re; }` and do this again - const method would be called

Comment: @threaz: Because it is the only function can be called. Isn't it?

Comment: @threaz You are correct, I didn't know that. Guess the best matching function is being called then. Actually come to think of it, I knew it, since I use them :) I knew that if you had both the const version only gets called on a const object (or pointer or reference).