# Get address of const method

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, decltype, function-qualifier

I would like to be able to form a pointer-to-member type knowing only the class itself and method name. Unfortunately I am not able to do so having a const and non-const method variants in my class.

Example code snippet:

```
struct A
{
    void method() {}
    void method() const {}
};

int main()
{
    decltype(&A::method) _;
}
```

I have also tried the following this but without much success either:

```
decltype(&(std::declval<const A>().method)) _;
```

Both approaches fail as `decltype` cannot resolve this due to ambiguity:

> `'decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function'`

How can I achieve this in some other way?

Comment: Doesn't having two functions like that create a problem due to an ambiguous signature?

Comment: @possum No, the const is sufficient to disambiguate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
struct A
{
    void method() {
        cout << "Non const\n";    
    }
    void method() const {
        cout << "const function\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef  void (A::*method_const)() const;
    method_const a = &A::method;     //address of const method
    
    typedef  void (A::*method_nonconst)();
    method_nonconst b = &A::method;  //address of non const method
    
    A var;
    std::invoke(a, var);
    std::invoke(b, var);
}
```

If you want to use `decltype()` to achieve the same thing, you first have to manually select the function you want using `static_cast<>`:

```
int main()
{
    //const
    decltype( static_cast <void (A::*)() const> (&A::method) ) a;
    //non const
    decltype( static_cast <void (A::*)()> (&A::method) ) b;
    
    a = &A::method;
    b = &A::method;
    
    A var;
    std::invoke(a, var);
    std::invoke(b, var);
}
```

[Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa70160db9ded54f)